# Date Conversion of yymmddhhmm.yymmddhhmm in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting this type of data in DateandTime Column in SQl.

`1803301611.1803301611`

Format is `yymmddhhmm.yymmddhhmm` and I have to convert this data in a date format.

The DateandTime Column date type is `Varchar(5)`

Comment: Which database are you using?  This looks like `YYMMDDHHMM` format to me.

Comment: yes your right @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Great, now just tell us which database you are using and maybe someone can help you.

Comment: i am using sql server

Comment: do you have any idea what date `1803301611` is meant to *correspond* to? If not, how will you know if any answer is *correct*? It would also help to have *more than one* example.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Already mentioned above by Mr Tim.

Comment: Varchar(5)? The example you've shown is 10 characters, please make sure you're looking at the right field.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen okay tim how to convert this formatted data into date only.

Comment: It would be better if it was *in the question*. Please [edit] and add more details, and get the tags sorted out at the same time. I doubt [tag:insight] is correct.

Comment: well i have corrected by myself

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the format of your time string can be directly converted by SQL Server.  But, we can try to piece together into a format which can be.  This is the closest I could come, and it required prepending a `20` in front of the year to make a full 4 digit century:

```
SELECT
    col AS input,
    CONVERT(datetime, '20' + SUBSTRING(col, 1, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(col, 3, 2) + '-' +
    SUBSTRING(col, 5, 2) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(col, 7, 2) + ':' +
    SUBSTRING(col, 9, 2), 120) AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

We ideally should have been able to use mask `20` without the century, but I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
select *, cast(concat(cast(left(col, 6) as date), ' ',stuff(right(col, 4), 3, 0, ':')
                           ) as datetime
              ) as newdatetime
from table t;
```